# Reduce width of submenu's container by media query

Tags: css

I tryed to apply a media queries to [this website](http://www.gabrielewebdesigner.it/work_site/dci/) 
I would change the width of the submenu's container .
This is the media query:

```
 @media (max-width: 800px) {
     .dropEverythingSub li.testing .dropEverything-page {
        width:200%;
    }
}
```

But when I reduce the window of the browser the width of this container remains the same.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Did you make sure that the browser windows is indeed less then 800px wide?

Comment: I tested on chrome and firefox. Yes, I'm sure about the width of browser window.

Comment: Sorry, I told you I was sure but I was in error about the window's width. I installed this extension to chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh
Now I can see the right width and personalize according to my needs.
Thanks.